# vectorization of a single loop in matlab (multiplication and then addition)

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I have a nX2 matrix A and a 3D matrix K. I would like to take element-wise multiplication specifying 2 indices in 3rd dimension of K designated by each row vector in A and take summation of them.

For instance of a simplified example when n=2,

```
A=[1 2;3 4];%2X2 matrix
K=unifrnd(0.1,0.1,2,2,4);%just random 3D matrix
L=zeros(2,2);%save result to here
for t=1:2
    L=L+prod(K(:,:,A(t,:)),3);
end
```

Can I get rid of the for loop in this case?

Comment: thanks for your comment. my mistake...

Comment: Does ``A`` always contain indexes of this form in this order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

```
B = A.'; %'
L = squeeze(sum(prod(...
                  reshape(permute(K(:,:,B(:)),[3 1 2]),2,[],size(K,1),size(K,2)),...
                  1),...
            2));
```

Although your test case is too simple, so I can't be entirely sure that it's correct.

The idea is that we first take all the indices in `A`, in column-major order, then reshape the elements of `K` such that the first two dimensions are of size `[2, n]`, and the second two dimensions are the original 2 of `K`. We then take the product, then the sum along the necessary dimensions, ending up with a matrix that has to be squeezed to get a 2d matrix.

---

Using a bit more informative test case:

```
K = rand(2,3,4);
A = randi(4,4,2);
L = zeros(2,3);%save result to here
for t=1:size(A,1)
    L = L+prod(K(:,:,A(t,:)),3);
end

B = A.'; %'
L2 = squeeze(sum(prod(reshape(permute(K(:,:,B(:)),[3 1 2]),2,[],size(K,1),size(K,2)),1),2));
```

Then

```
>> isequal(L,L2)
ans =
     1
```

Comment: @JaeminSon there's a high chance that Divakar's answer is faster. Check out both.

Answer (score 2):

With some [`reshaping`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) *`magic`* -

```
%// Get sizes
[m1,n1,r1] = size(K);
[m2,n2] = size(A);

%// Index into 3rd dim of K; perform reductions and reshape back
Lout = reshape(sum(prod(reshape(K(:,:,A'),[],n2,m2),2),3),m1,n1);
```

Explanation :

1. Index into the third dimension of `K` with a transposed version of `A` (transposed because we are using rows of A for indexing).
2. Perform the `prod()` and `sum()` operations.
3. Finally reshape back to a shape same as `K` but without the third dimension as that was removed in the earlier reduction steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, why did you reshape K into Kr? If I use
Lout = reshape(sum(prod(reshape(K(:,:,A'),[],n2,m2),2),3),m1,n1);
without reshaping or Kr, doesn't it lead to the same result?

Comment: @JaeminSon Ah yes! My silly *mind*! Yes, that would work too and much simpler! Let me edit the post.

Comment: Thanks Divakar for your answer anyway! by the way, 
Lout3 = sum(prod(reshape(K(:,:,At),m1,n1,n2,m2),3),4);
looks ok as well without reshaping in the end as well.

Comment: @JaeminSon Yup, that should work too. In that one, the reductions are performed later on, that's the only difference.

Comment: can you explain what reductions are? does that refer to reshaping a matrix?

Comment: @JaeminSon By reduction I mean operations like `sum` and `prod`, using which the number of elements are reduced and hence the name `reduction` operations or simply `reductions`.

Comment: oh I see. Thanks a lot for your help!